# Smarter GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by

Consider Table like this.
I will call it Test

```
Id  A   B   C   D
1   1   1   8   25
2   1   2   5   35
3   1   3   2   75
4   2   2   2   45
5   3   2   5   26
```

Now I want rows with max 'Id' Grouped by 'A'

```
Id  A   B   C   D
3   1   3   2   75
4   2   2   2   45
5   3   2   5   26
```

-

```
--Work, but I do not want
SELECT  MAX(Id), A           FROM  Test GROUP BY A
--I want but do not work           
SELECT  MAX(Id), A, B, C, D  FROM  Test GROUP BY A 
--Work but I do not want         
SELECT  MAX(Id), A, B, C, D  FROM  Test GROUP BY A, B, C, D  
--Work and I want   
SELECT old.Id, old.A, new.B, new.C, new.D  
FROM(
   SELECT 
       MAX(Id) AS Id, A
   FROM 
       Test GROUP BY A
   )old
JOIN Test new
ON old.Id = new.Id
```

Is there a better way to write last query without join

Comment: tag the question with the dbms being used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most databases support `window functions`:

```
select * 
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by a order by id desc) rn
    from test
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Most DBMS now support Common Table Expressions (CTE). You can use one.

```
;with maxa as (
select row_number() over(partition by a order by id desc) rn,
id,a,b,c,d from test
)
select id,a,b,c,d
from maxa
where rn=1
```

Comment: Why a CTE instead of the direct query?

Comment: OP wants `max(id)` with all columns unchanged. Aggregate functions with group by doesn't return what they want.

Comment: How it change columns?